# Refresh ListView after updating in another Activity

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have two simple Activities -
Activity1: ListView from an Array
Activity2: EditText for editing the clicked row in Activity1

When I edit the value in Activity2 and returning to Activity1, the ListView doesn't reload the new value.

I want to refresh the ListView when I return from Activity2 or resume Activity1 or something that will update the list.

My code:

```
static ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Loading the values to list array
        String[][] fulllist = loadArrays();
        String[] list = new String[fulllist.length];
        for(int i = 0; i<fulllist.length; i++) {
            list[i] =  fulllist[i][1];
            }
            // --------------------------------

            dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                                list);
            setListAdapter(dataAdapter);
            }
@Override
public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Loading the values to list array
        String[][] fulllist = loadArrays();
        String[] list = new String[fulllist.length];
        for(int i = 0; i<fulllist.length; i++) {
            list[i] =  fulllist[i][1];
            }
        // --------------------------------

        dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                            list);
        dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

loadArrays() is just method that converts from SharedPreferences to String Array. Activity2 saves the new data in SharedPreferences and than Activity1 can read it (with the new data).
If I return to the "main activity" (it is not Activity1) and than come back to Activity1 - the new data is shown, but I want this data will be updated when I return from Activity2 immediately.

loadArrays() method: pastebin.com/MHwNC0jK

Thanking you in advance!

Comment: code for loadArrays() will help better understand

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On clicking the item in your first Activity, start your second Activity with `startActivityForResult()`

And then in Second Activity, after entering in `EditText`, probably there is a button. And in `onClick` of that button call,

```
intent.putExtra("edittextvalue", findViewById(R.id.edittext).getText().toString());
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

Now you come back to your first Activity and here you have to implement `onActivityResult()` callback. You can extract data from that intent's extras and set that respective item in your array and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

This is ideally how you should be doing it.

If you want more info on how to use startActivityForResult() try this link - http://manisivapuram.blogspot.in/2011/06/how-to-use-startactivityforresult.html

Comment: This will give me a little different data and result than I wanted, but I will check it.

Answer (score 1):

1) Get reference ListView

```
mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.auto_listview);
```

2) Create adapter One more time with changed values

```
MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 
                                    R.layout.locations_list_item_layout,dataArray;
mListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView,
                        View view, int i, long l) {

myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 
    //pass changed values vlues array                               R.layout.locations_list_item_layout,dataArray;
mListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

}

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
```

Answer (score -3):

Declare fulllist as Globle Variable and used static arraylist .